# how to convert XFA forms to Arcoforms in python3?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to use aspose.pdf.xfaconverter in "Aspose.PDF for Python via .NET" to resolve this problem.The help document url is [https://reference.aspose.com/pdf/net/aspose.pdf.xfaconverter/。I](https://reference.aspose.com/pdf/net/aspose.pdf.xfaconverter/%E3%80%82I) don`t know how to do.Thanks for you help!!

I want to convert XFA forms to Arcoforms in python3